# .blur and .onblur in chrome

Tags: jquery

updated not working --- http://jsfiddle.net/xvepL/4/ driving me a bit nuts! Chrome doesnt use .blur only works with .onblur but other browsers use .blur is there a way around this? It also both ways does not work on select lists?

NO fiddle as its browser specific

```
/* Big Search Box Leave */
    $(".searchbox").onblur(function() {
    var searchbox = this,
        searchbox_val = $.trim( this.value );
    if (searchbox_val.length > 0) {
        $(searchbox).addClass("blur");
        return true;
    } else {
        $(searchbox).removeClass("blur");
        return false;
    }
  });
```

Comment: just tried your snippet in Chrome, didn't work until I change it to `blur` instead of `onblur` assuming jquery is returning a standard `<input ... />` element?

Comment: Why not use `.change()` function?

Comment: Also, `onblur` is incorrect.  It should be `blur` everywhere.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/xvepL/4/ - still doesnt work???

Answer (score 2):

`$(".searchbox").onblur` is incorrect.  `.onblur()` is not a jQuery function.  On the other hand, [`.blur()`](http://api.jquery.com/blur/) is.

```
$(".searchbox").blur(function () {
    var searchbox = this,
        searchbox_val = $.trim(this.value);
    if (searchbox_val.length > 0) {
        $(searchbox).addClass("blur");
        return true;
    } else {
        $(searchbox).removeClass("blur");
        return false;
    }
});
```

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/xvepL/2/ (Works fine in Chrome)

Note: `.onblur` is the name of the property if you were dealing with DOM elements and *not* jQuery objects.

```
document.getElementsByClassName('searchbox').onblur = function(){
};
```

Comment: I made a demo too, here's the raw output; run it in Chrome and it works as expected: http://fiddle.jshell.net/sellmeadog/kNtMD/show/light/

Comment: @david: Yup, works fine on a `<select>`.  I added that to my example: http://jsfiddle.net/xvepL/1/

Comment: @david: If you use `this.value` on a `<select>`, and the selected `<option>` doesn't have a `value` attribute, it'll return the `<option>`'s text.  That may have been your issue.  Check my newest example: http://jsfiddle.net/xvepL/2/

Comment: @david: In your HTML and JavaScript you have `searchlist`, but in your CSS you have `selectlist`.

Comment: rocket i dont think it can be the other states as it works for the input??

Comment: @david: It works fine for the select (it gets the class `blur`).  Check your CSS.