# Rails 4: getting form field value with CoffeeScript

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, forms, ruby-on-rails-4, coffeescript

In my Rails 4 app, I use Bootstrap 3 and regular Rails forms (**NOT** Simple Form).

In one of my forms, I have a `datetime` field:

```
<div class="field">
  <%= f.label :date, "DATE & TIME" %>
  <%= f.datetime_select :date %>
</div>
```

On this field, I use the `bootstrap3-datetimepicker-rails` gem ([see here](https://github.com/TrevorS/bootstrap3-datetimepicker-rails)) to allow users to pick a date and a time more easily.

The corresponding HTML code is:

```
<div class="field">
  <label for="date">DATE &amp; TIME</label>
  <div class="input-group"><input value="Wednesday, December 23 2015 09:41 AM" class="form-control datetimepicker" data-date-format="dddd, MMMM DD YYYY hh:mm A" type="text" name="post[date]" id="date"><span class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span></span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Now, I want to display a custom message on the same page, in a specific `#date_analysis` div, in live, based on the day of the date they select.

For instance, if the day of the selected date is Monday, I want to display "Monday is good", but if the day is Tuesday, I want to display "Tuesday is bad", and so on, with a custom message for each day.

At the moment, I have the following code:

```
$(document).ready ->
  date_analysis = (day) ->
    if day == "Monday"
      $('#date_analysis').html 'Monday is good.'
    else if day == "Tuesday"
      $('#date_analysis').html 'Tuesday is bad.'
  day = $('#date').val().split(",")[0]
  $('#date').onBlur ->
    date_analysis(day)
```

The only problem is that, when the user updates the date in the field with the datetimepicker, the `value` in the source code is not updated.

—————

**UPDATE 1**: What I mean by

> the `value` in the source code is not updated

is that `<input value="Wednesday, December 23 2015 09:41 AM" ...>` remains the same when I inspect elements, regardless of the date I choose with the datetimepicker.

—————

Because of that, the `date_analysis` function always returns the same value.

How can I get the value of the date selected by the user then?

—————

**UPDATE 2**: it seems that now I get the following error in the Chrome console:

```
Uncaught TypeError: $(...).onBlur is not a function
```

I have tried updating the Rails form as follows:

```
<div class="field">
  <%= f.label :date, "DATE & TIME" %>
  <%= f.datetime_select :date, :onblur => 'date_analysis()' %>
</div>
```

as recommended [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13600850/how-to-add-an-onchange-listener-for-form-elements-in-ruby-on-rails) for instance.

But I still get the same error.

Any idea?

—————

**UPDATE 3**: as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11587507/blur-and-onblur-in-chrome):

> `.onblur` is the name of the property if you were dealing with DOM
>   elements and not jQuery objects.

So, I tried instead:

```
<div class="field">
  <%= f.label :date, "DATE & TIME" %>
  <%= f.datetime_select :date, :onBlur => 'post_date_analysis()' %>
</div>
```

Now, I don't get any error, but I don't get the results I expect either.

Any idea what's wrong here?

Comment: In your code `$('#date').onBlur ->
    date_analysis(day)`, where `day` is coming from?

Comment: Thanks for your comment. `day` comes from `date_analysis = (day)`.

Comment: Sorry, the information in my previous comment is incorrect. `day` comes from `day = $('#date').val().split(",")[0]`.